# breeze get a collection of entities not objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, breeze

Using a restful **node.js** server and sending a collection of entities wrapped in one entity object (Lookups) everything works, but the entities in the collection are seen as plain objects and not entities by **breeze**. Is there a way to fix this, also instead of using an entity for the Lookups is it possible to use a complex object since its used just as a holder and nothing more. Thanks for the help

The response from the server is in this format

```
[
  oranges:[{id:1, name:'juicy'}, {id:2, name:'no seeds'}],
  apples:[{id:1, name:'red'}, {id:2, name:'green'}]
]
```

using this query:

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from('users/lookups')
            .using(this.manager).execute()
            .then(this.querySucceeded)
            .catch(this.queryFailed);
```

Here is the metadata code for the lookup

```
var entityType = {
   name: this.entityNames.Lookup,
   defaultResourceName: 'users/lookups',
   autoGeneratedKeyType: breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
   dataProperties: {
      lookupID: {dataType: DT.Int32, isPartOfKey: true}
   },
   navigationProperties:  {
      apples: {
             entityTypeName: this.entityNames.Apple
       },
      orange: {
             entityTypeName: this.entityNames.Orange
       }
   }
};
```

The meta for the Orange and Apple

```
var entityType = {
    name: this.entityNames.Apple,
    defaultResourceName: 'users/lookups/Apples',
    dataProperties: {
         id: {type: DT.Int32},
         image: {type: DT.String},
         name: { complexTypeName: 'Translation:#model', isNullable: false}
    }
 };


var entityType = {
    name: this.entityNames.Orange,
    defaultResourceName: 'users/lookups/Oranges',
    dataProperties: {
         id: {type: DT.Int32},
         image: {type: DT.String},
         name: { complexTypeName: 'Translation:#model', isNullable: false}
    }
 };
```

The meta for complex type Translation

```
var entityType = {
    name: 'Translation',
    isComplexType: true,
    dataProperties: {
         fr: {type: DT.String},
         en: {type: DT.String}
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server response for apples and oranges should have the types identified in the response data.  That way they can be recognized as the entities they are:

```
[
  oranges:[
    {$type:model.Orange, id:1, name:'juicy'}, 
    {$type:model.Orange, id:2, name:'no seeds'}
  ],
  apples:[
    {$type:model.Apple, id:1, name:'red'}, 
    {$type:model.Apple, id:2, name:'green'}
  ]
]
```

You can see more about [lookups in the Breeze documentation](http://breeze.github.io/doc-cool-breezes/lookup-lists.html)

Comment: The $type attribute did the job like magic, thanks that would have taken me ages. What about the Lookup Entity can i change it to a complex type or does it need to be an Entity for it to work. Thank you once more

Comment: You don't need a lookup entity at all.  Just send back the response, and Breeze will put any entities in the response into the cache.  Breeze won't cache the outer object if it is not an entity.